# Flutter if else condition in child

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

I am working on a flutter quiz application and it fetches question and images from JSON file 
When the app is running in question with no images I am getting a loading symbol & I need to remove that loading symbol in question with no images using if but I am running into errors I am attaching the Psuedo Code can someone tell how can I do it ???

```
 Expanded(
                              child: AspectRatio(
                                aspectRatio: 16 / 11,
                                child: ClipRect(
                                  child: SizedBox(
                                    height: 50,
                                    child: PhotoView(
                                      imageProvider: AssetImage(
                                          myQuestion[i]["Image"] ?? "None"),
                                      minScale:
                                      PhotoViewComputedScale.contained *
                                          0.5,
                                      maxScale:
                                      PhotoViewComputedScale.covered * 2,
                                      initialScale: 0.6,
                                      backgroundDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        color: Theme.of(context).canvasColor,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
```

Comment: you can make the if return the photoview or an empty final container according to the right case

Comment: Can you show how will it be done properly I am running into errors I am a novice with flutter and dart

Comment: can you just post a sample json

Comment: i guess something like this... child: ( myQuestion[i]["Image"] != null ) ? PhotoView(imageProvider: AssetImage(
                                          myQuestion[i]["Image"] ...) : Container(),

Comment: like the response by Sar Putnik

Comment: I tried using the solution but still, image loading occurs
To check if the empty container is working I added a text but still for questions with no images container is not being loaded
This is what is being shown in the console: Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: " ")
Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#8c116(), name: " ", scale: 1.0)
My JSON file is something like this 
"Question": "C99 standard guarantees uniqueness of ____ characters for internal names.",
"Image": " ",
Image path is provided in questions with images

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment yet. And I don't know exactly what kind of error you're running in but I think is the string being provided as the image source.

You can move the logic check from the AssetImage higher in the widget tree.

```
Expanded(
  child: AspectRatio(
    aspectRatio: 16 / 11,
    child: ClipRect(
      child: SizedBox(
        height: 50,
        child: myQuestion[i]["Image"]!=null && myQuestion[i]["Image"].isNotEmpty() 
           ? PhotoView(
               imageProvider: AssetImage( myQuestion[i]["Image"] ), // we know it's not empty and is not null
               minScale: PhotoViewComputedScale.contained * 0.5,
               maxScale: PhotoViewComputedScale.covered * 2,
               initialScale: 0.6,
               backgroundDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                 color: Theme.of(context).canvasColor,
               ),
             )
           : Container(),
         ),
      ),
   ),
),
```

We use a ternary operator to check if the asset is not null and is not empty. If it has a valid value we display the image otherwise we display and empty container. This logic can be moved up the widget tree depending on what you want to display and where.

Comment: I tried using the solution but still, image loading occurs To check if the empty container is working I added a text but still for questions with no images container is not being loaded This is what is being shown in the console: Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: " ") Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#8c116(), name: " ", scale: 1.0) My JSON file is something like this "Question": "C99 standard guarantees uniqueness of ____ characters for internal names.", "Image": " ", the Image path is provided in questions with images